# A poem of dynamic words

Tags: word, rhyme, wordplay

In many great novels, to the reader I appear
Adjust me, and I describe things that are near

Once more, and my meaning changes only slightly
Again, and you excercised your free will, rightly

Yet another, and I'm something we all ought to do
Again, I'm a boundary with a beautiful view

Again, I'm a place to which many must go
And again, I'm a thing wise men shouldn't throw

Now behead me, I'm a thing you must watch while you speak
*Your next action depends on the word that you seek:*

Behead me once more, and my use is widespread
Or instead take my foot, of hard things I am said

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In many great novels, to the reader I appear

> Great novels have a very compelling **theme**.

Adjust me, and I describe things that are near

> Would you perhaps be referencing **these**, over here? (m -> s)

Once more, and my meaning changes only slightly

> Or perhaps you mean **those**? (e -> o)

Again, and you exercised your free will, rightly

> If you exercised your free will, you **chose** something. (t -> c)

Yet another, and I'm something we all ought to do

> I thought this was share, but it turns out we should all do a **chore** once in awhile. (s -> r)

Again, I'm a boundary with a beautiful view

> Especially beautiful at sunset or sunrise, this references the **shore**. (c -> s)

Again, I'm a place to which many must go

> If you need to buy something, you have to go to the **store**. (h -> t)

And again, I'm a thing wise men shouldn't throw

> If you're wise, you will throw no **stone**. (r -> n)

Now behead me, I'm a thing you must watch while you speak

> I know I've heard this from my mother: you better watch your **tone**! (goodbye, s)

Behead me once more, and my use is widespread

> The number **one** is a pretty widespread number, I'd say. (goodbye, t)

Or instead take my foot, of hard things I am said

> That thing must weigh a **ton**! (goodbye, e)

Comment: Very nice! I have that right up to the 'Your next action depends on the word that you seek'... I *really* wanted to find a word that actually describes the action of adding, removing, or changing a letter. Your decision to treat that line as filler is probably what is intended, however.

Comment: @BoboDClown ah, I see what you're saying - I immediately read it as filler and glossed right over it!

Comment: I was hoping that wouldn't trip people up! Excellent work, Bailey. May I ask which word you got first, or did you start with "theme" and follow them in order?

Comment: @Roland, I got 'stone' and 'tone' at about the same time and worked my way backwards. :)