# Who's missing from this glorious Poem of Dynamic Words?

Tags: word, rhyme, wordplay

I'm where you keep your most private possessions
With a small adjustment, I'm always on the move
Again, and I'm one of you, lacking aggression
Once more, at my end, my son has something to prove

If you gut *him*, you may have done so for this
Change that, and a group of great beasts have you found
Again, it's my versatile partner, my bliss
She protects me when orderly enemies are 'round

Make a rhyme, if you've done a good job it will squeak
Sort them out and you'll find a great tool comes to view
*This weapon, however, is not the word that you seek:*
It's the user, of which, in my land I have two

Take his opposite, and several later you've got one
Change its first, and this riddle's answer you *desire*
Conjugate incorrectly, and you've not got a verb, son
But one close to this soldier, in his path, you'll retire.

Again, recall the user of the weapon above
When his opposite appears, it is given this name
One fix and you've found my minions least loved
But without them I'd be at a loss in this game

---

**Disclaimer:** This riddle is intended to be a much harder follow-up to my [quickly solved puzzle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/18727/a-poem-of-dynamic-words) last week. At the end of each line, you should be left with a one-syllable, common word. **Only lines 11 and 20 do not yield a word.** Most words will only change by one letter between lines, as hinted, but this riddle is more complex: phrases like *gut him*, *sort them out*, and *take his opposite* should be interpreted analogously to *behead me* from the previous riddle, which was wordplay for *remove my first letter*.

- All words are one syllable long, and no longer than six letters
- All words should be well known by the community

  - Exception: Line 15 jokes that its word is an incorrect conjugation of [14]. I didn't know that it was even a word, but apparently it has an obscure definition.
- No proper nouns are used in this puzzle

Other words will change completely across line pairs, but I hope not to confuse you too badly, so I'll provide **hints here:**
**Hint 1:**

> From line 4 to 5, our first odd pair appears
>  Hark! From first to third person it veers!

**Hint 2:**

> In lines 7 and 8, the subject is the same
>  For [8], the [7] of [4] is given this name.

**Hint 3:**

> Line 3 describes its word in two separate ways
>  It makes a good place to begin solving this maze.

Comment: First line looks like either PURSE or PANTS :-)

Comment: In your other dynamic poem, words only ever changed by one letter at a time. Can you confirm that rule applies to this one too?

Comment: Some words change by a letter, as hinted, but others will play with letters differently. There are also changes that are rhyming, wordplay, and antonyms, but it works the same in that parts can be solved backwards if your first word is in the middle.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification and the hints. I know now I am on the right track (I wasn't sure because of the larger changes). Still not sure how to connect all I've got so far though - maybe in a weeks time ;).

Comment: Thanks for asking. I think some of the lines were a little too cryptic, especially from line 7 to 8. Good skill solving the puzzle!

Comment: Just to confirm, is *every* word between 1 and 5 characters long?

Comment: Thanks for asking! Some 6-letter words are used, but every word is one syllable. I'll update the puzzle.

Comment: Is the word for line 4 a reference to a specific man, hence _him_ in the next line?

Comment: I'm stumped by lines 12 and 13, but apart from that I think I've got it. What I've got for 14 makes sense in its own right, and I can justify the leap to 15, but 13 just doesn't seem to fit :( - I am enjoying this whole thing though!

Comment: @greenglass hurry up and solve it! I'm dying to see the answer!

Comment: @5813 see the bullet points I've added in the disclaimer. If you're asking whether to take "my son" literally, my answer is "Yes"

Comment: @BaileyM see below - hopefully I got it right ;)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Who is missing?

> The bishop

I'm where you keep your most private possessions

> My most private possessions are my thoughts, which I keep in my **mind**

With a small adjustment, I'm always on the move

> The **wind** is always on the move

Again, and I'm one of you, lacking aggression

> Of my **kind**, or to be **kind**

Once more, at my end, my son has something to prove

> The son of a **king** would have something to prove

If you gut him, you may have done so for this

> **price** (see comments, thanks @Lampost42)

Change that, and a group of great beasts have you found

> A group of lions is a **pride**

Again, it's my versatile partner, my bliss

> A partner or a **bride**

Who protects me when orderly enemies are 'round

> of a king would be a **queen** - a versatile and powerful chess piece

Make a rhyme, if you've done a good job it will squeak

> as in, squeaky **clean**

Sort them out and you'll find a great tool comes to view

> clean is an anagram of **lance**

This weapon, however, is not the word that you seek
It's the user, of which, in my land I have two

> and a lance is the weapon of a **knight**, of which there are two per chess player

Take his opposite, and several later you've got one

> The opposite of night is day, and several days is a **week**

Change its first, and this riddle's answer you desire

> It took me a while to notice the italics around desire, but once I did it could be replaced with **seek**

Conjugate incorrectly, and you've not got a verb, son

> The past of seek is sought, and a **sook** is (apparently) a female crab

But one close to this soldier, in his path, you'll retire.

> You wouldn't want your king in the path of a **rook**

Again, recall the user of the weapon above

> back to **knight**

When his opposite appears, it is given this name

> the appearance of day is **dawn**

One fix and you've found my minions least loved

> the least appreciated piece in chess is a **pawn**

But without them I'd be at a loss in this game

> and although the edit says this doesn't yield a word, I think it could yield **chess**

Comment: Excellent work! One (and only one) of your words is wrong, though. I'm sure someone, or yourself, will catch it, but I'll give a strong hint in a little bit if it goes unsolved. +1

Comment: I believe "if you gut him" refers to the kings son or the prince. Removing the n, "gutting" him, gives you price.

Comment: Thanks @Lampost42 - it seems so obvious now you've pointed it out! Thanks for a satisfying (and infuriating) puzzle Roland

Comment: That was an awesome answer to an awesome puzzle.

Comment: @BaileyM Thanks, but for some reason this riddle was the least viewed of the one's I've written. Do you know why (or how) some riddles get 1k views in an hour while others get <50 per day?

Comment: @Roland some of it has to do with the Hot Network Questions over on the sidebar. I don't quite know how questions show up there, but they show up there across all of Stack Exchange and get a LOT of views because of it.