# A wonderfully poor poem

Tags: word, wordplay, poetry

*To start, I'm strangely missing.

Modified, I'm what a silly chef lacks.

Again, and I'm subtly present.

Do me harm, and I'm perhaps you.*

*With a change, I'm tall and resilient.

Again, and this is certainly that.

Again, I'm a guitarist's worry.

Again, and I'll make a stand.

Again, and our paths will cross.

Again, and I'm some kind of kind of cat.*

*Adorn me, and I'm also strangely missing.

Enrich me, and I'll destroy everything.

Destroy me, and I'm a secluded commander.

Chop me down, and my feelings are obvious.*

*With a swap, I've been judged.

With another, I'm a torrid remainder.

And with another, I'm a torrid beginner.

And a last, you'd better turn me.*

*Top down, I'm virtually nonexistent.

With a flip, you can find me within.

Decorate me, and I'm a young helper.

And again, I'm a soft, brimmed hat --

One more change, and this is certainly not that!*

---

<sup>Note: This is a **[dynamic poem](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/18767/whos-missing-from-this-glorious-poem-of-dynamic-words)**, meaning that each line references a word, and the words change slightly between each line. There is a motif behind this poem, which encompasses six of the lines. A complete answer will explain each line, as well as the overarching motif of the poem. Also, I promise that this time [the lines are in the right order](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/20245/a-crumbled-jumbled-poem)!</sup>

Comment: Awesome. I feel compelled to keep solving (I have a few lines, I think), but I ought to get more work done. Today's lunch break might be longer than normal... :)

Comment: "some kind of kind of cat" -- typo, or clue?

Comment: @dennisdeems there are no typos in this poem! I think. That's definitely not one though.

Comment: If I could solve one of your puzzles then I would die happy

Comment: @SirParselot I believe in you! This is the one!

Comment: Gah! I'm so close but hindered by one line!

Comment: @NeedAName which line?

Comment: 'Destroy me and I'm a secluded commander'. It may be that I did the previous line wrong, but I don't readily see a better alternative

Comment: @NeedAName ah, here we go - 'Destroy me' indicates a change to the word you have not yet used in the process of solving this puzzle. It's not a simple "remove-one-letter" kind of thing.

Comment: Would you say the same of the previous operation as well (that it is an operation hitherto unperformed)?

Comment: @NeedAName why yes, I believe that I would.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I figured out the first stanza last, and I'm least sure about the explanations for this set of words. You'd think you'd need to nail this down to get a solid foundation for figuring out the rest of the poem, but...well, here goes.

*To start, I'm strangely missing.*

> **RHYME** - This poem has barely any rhyming lines, and there certainly isn't a rhyme in this line. And for those of us struggling with this puzzle, it may have seemed to lack “rhyme or reason" (make no sense, have no logic).

*Modified, I'm what a silly chef lacks.*

> **THYME** (modify by replacing R with T) - Maybe the chef is punny and has neither the herb thyme nor time to prepare dishes.

*Again, and I'm subtly present.*

> **THEME** (modify again by replacing Y with E) - @Bailey already mentioned that there's a theme or motif within this poem.

*Do me harm, and I'm perhaps you.*

> **THEE** (harm by removing M) - The objective case of the word “thou", an archaic form of “you"

*With a change, I'm tall and resilient.*

> **TREE** (change H to R) - Both words can describe a tree.

*Again, and this is certainly that.*

> **FREE** (change T to F) - This poem is an example of free verse, having no pattern in rhyme or meter.

*Again, I'm a guitarist's worry.*

> **FRET** (change E to T) - Part of a guitar as well as a synonym for “worry"

*Again, and I'll make a stand.*

> **FEET** (change R to E) - Organisms with feet stand on them. For the poem motif, they are groups of syllables in a meter.

*Again, and our paths will cross.*

> **MEET** (change H to M) - To cross paths is to meet.

*Again, and I'm some kind of kind of cat.*

> **MEER** (change T to R) - cat -> kat -> meerkat (an animal)

*Adorn me, and I'm also strangely missing.*

> **METER** (adorn by inserting T) - This poem doesn't seem to follow a meter, a pattern of stressed and unstressed syllables.

*Enrich me, and I'll destroy everything.*

> **METEOR** (enrich by inserting O) - A collision with a meteor is very destructive. Ask the dinosaurs.

*Destroy me, and I'm a secluded commander.*

> **REMOTE** (destroy by rearranging letters) - A synonym for “secluded" as well as a device that can command or control other devices

*Chop me down, and my feelings are obvious.*

> **EMOTE** (chop by removing R) - Word for showing feelings

*With a swap, I've been judged.*

> **SMOTE** (swap E with S) - Possible punishment after judgement, especially from a deity

*With another, I'm a torrid remainder.*

> **SMOKE** (swap T with K) - What usually remains after something torrid like a fire

*And with another, I'm a torrid beginner.*

> **STOKE** (swap M with T) - What one does to start or feed a fire

*And a last, you'd better turn me.*

> **STONE** (swap K with N) - From the idiom “leave no stone unturned"

*Top down, I'm virtually nonexistent.*

> **TONE** (remove top or first letter) - This poem doesn't seem to have a tone or mood, besides a puzzling one.

*With a flip, you can find me within.*

> **BONE** (flip by swapping T with B) - As human beings, we have an internal skeleton of bones.

*Decorate me, and I'm a young helper.*

> **BONNE** (decorate by inserting N) - French word for maidservant

*And again, I'm a soft, brimmed hat --*

> **BONNET** (insert again with T) - Yup, it's a type of hat.

*One more change, and this is certainly not that!*

> **SONNET** (final change by swapping B with S) - A 14-line poem of a specific scheme, which this dynamic puzzle poem isn't.

Overarching motif is

> this is a poem about a poem or prosodical terms: rhyme, free, feet, meter, tone, sonnet. Despite my name's meaning - no, really, part of it means poem - I'm unable to explain further at the moment. Sorry if I missed any details or just missed.

My mobile device is ill suited for composing this answer.

Comment: You got it! Unfortunately, the silly chef is indeed out of thyme. :( Also, 'theme' falls under the parts of the poem, but you got everything else other than that. Well done!

Comment: Yay, thanks! You've helped push my reputation up where I can actually comment properly. Your poem made me feel like I've done something this weekend. I thought about including "theme", but the motif hint mentioned six lines, and I'm literal sometimes.