# I am used to comprehend

Tags: riddle, english

> I am used to comprehend
>   Add one letter and I'm your food
>   Move a letter to be magical
>   Drop a letter to quiver in fear

*What exactly am I talking about?*

Comment: These are simple, fun, and easy to come up with.

Comment: Just be careful they don't turn into a craze of mass-produced crappy puzzles like the spaghetti/rebus ones...

Comment: @rand al'thor Oh yeah. Fun times lol

Comment: spaghetti/rebus?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*I am used to comprehend*

> You often comprehend things by READing them.

*Add one letter and I'm your food*

> BREAD is a kind of food.

*Move a letter to be magical*

> Wizards stereotypically have long BEARDs.

*Drop a letter to quiver in fear*

> A BEAR might make someone quiver in fear.

Comment: Well done! You must have a really long beard because your answering skills are certainly magical :)

Comment: "to be magical" = BEARD? Is warspyking launching a campaign to kill this form of puzzle?

Comment: @warspyking, if that's the intended answer then a) the question needs some indication that each modification is of the previous line, rather than the first line; b) the only answer which really fits the clue is the second one.

Comment: @Roland He's famous for asking crappy questions: having more questions than anyone else on the site, but most of them with negative scores. No offence, warspy - *some* of your puzzles have been great!

Comment: @randal'thor [My poems](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/18727/a-poem-of-dynamic-words) are my babies, and as their creator, I'm a little hurt by the last hour's deluge of word puzzles.

Comment: @rand al'thor You nailed me!

Comment: Just for the record, I do have (excluding deleted questions) far more 0+ questions than negatively scored questions. I can't count deleted because I can't find them...